# Triggering an Action.Execute on an adaptive card sent by a chat bot on Teams mobile apps caused a "Something Went Wrong" error

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

### Versions

Package: botbuilder@4.11.0

Nodejs: v16.19.0

Teams Android Client: 1416/1.0.0/2023012702/0115

I have a chatbot that functions as a notification bot that sends an adaptive card notification to our users.
On the card, the user can reply to the notification by typing in the Input.Text field and then clicking a send button that triggers an Action.Execute, our Nodejs bot will then process the activity by sending notifications to corresponding user and then updating the card with a new card.
This works perfectly on Web and Desktop app but in the Teams Android App the card will briefly shows an error message saying "Something went wrong" before our card is finally updated.

These is the card that I send:

```
{
      "type": "AdaptiveCard",
      "appId": process.env.MicrosoftBotAppId,
      "body": [
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": message,
          "wrap": true
        },
        {
          "id": "history_title",
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": cardString.pastEvents,
          "wrap": true
        },
        {
          "type": "Container",
          "spacing": "None",
          "items": [
            {
              "id": "last_trail_name",
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": lastTrail ? cardString.action(lastTrail.userName, lastTrailAction) : "",
              "spacing": "None",
              // "size": "Small",
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "id": "last_trail_comment",
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": lastTrail ? `${lastTrail.comment.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")}` : "",
              "spacing": "None",
              // "size": "Small",
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "id": "last_trail_date",
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": lastTrail ? `${lastTrailDateString}` : "",
              "spacing": "None",
              "isSubtle": true,
              "size": "Small",
              "wrap": true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "Container",
          "items": [
            {
              "id": "second_last_trail_name",
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": secondLastTrail ? cardString.action(secondLastTrail.userName, secondLastTrailAction) : "",
              "spacing": "None",
              // "size": "Small",
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "id": "second_last_trail_comment",
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": secondLastTrail ? `${secondLastTrail.comment.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")}` : "",
              "spacing": "None",
              // "size": "Small",
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "id": "second_last_trail_date",
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": secondLastTrail ? `${secondLastTrailDateString}` : "",
              "spacing": "None",
              "isSubtle": true,
              "size": "Small",
              "wrap": true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "comment",
          "isRequired": true,
          "type": "Input.Text",
          "placeholder": cardString.commentPlaceholder,
          "isMultiline": true
        },
        {
          "id": "success-msg",
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": success ? cardString.commentSentAlert : "",
          "spacing": "None",
          "isSubtle": true,
          "size": "Small",
          "wrap": true,
          "color": "good"
        }
      ],
      "actions": [
        {
          // "tooltip": isPremium ? cardString.send : cardString.premiumTooltip,
          // "isEnabled": isPremium, 
          "type": "Action.Execute",
          "verb": "comment",
          "title": cardString.send,
          "data": data,
        },
        {
          "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
          "title": cardString.goToTicketButton,
          "url": deeplink
        }
      ],
      "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
      "version": "1.4"
    }
```

And this is the bot that processed the action:

```
class Bot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
      super();

      this.onMembersAdded(async (turnContext: TurnContext, next: () => Promise<any>) => {
        const gettingStartedUrl: string = 'https://www.teamswork.app/gettingstarted';
        const membersAdded = turnContext.activity.membersAdded;
        for (let cnt = 0; cnt < membersAdded.length; cnt++) {
          if (membersAdded[cnt].id !== turnContext.activity.recipient.id) {
            const welcomeMessage = "Welcome message"

            // add conv references
            if (await this.storeConversationReference(turnContext))
              await turnContext.sendActivity(welcomeMessage); // Only send notification if conversation reference store (one time)
          }
        }

        // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
        await next();
      });
    }
    // Listener for activity e.g. comment activity on notification card
    async onInvokeActivity(turnContext: TurnContext): Promise<InvokeResponse<any>> {
      // Listen for activity invocation and check if the comment action on adaptiveCard has been called
      const activity: Activity = turnContext.activity;
      // context.log('activity: ', activity);
      // turnContext.sendActivity("Hello World!");
      let card: object;

      if (activity.name === "adaptiveCard/action") {
        // context.log("action activity");
        const action = activity.value.action;
        // context.log("action : ", action);
        if (action.verb === "comment") {
          const userName: string = activity.from.name;
          const userId: string = activity.from.aadObjectId;
          const data: IActionData = action.data;
          // context.log('data: ', action.data);
          const date: Date = new Date();
          const tenantId: string = activity.conversation.tenantId;
          const comment: string = data.comment;
          const lang: string = data.lang || "en";

          // assignee Ticket == user commennt
          if ((data.ticket.assigneeId == userId) && (data.ticket.firstTimeResponse == "")) {
            this.updateTicket(data.ticket)
          }
          // Check for ticketId
          if (!!!data.ticket) {
            context.log("No ticketId found, aborting");
            // throw ("No ticketId found, aborting")
          }

          // Construct new audit trail / comment
          let newComment: IAuditTrail = {
            userName: userName,
            userId: userId,
            ticketId: data.ticket.id,
            action: "commented",
            comment: comment,
            date: date,
          }

          // initialize parameters for card to be sent
          const cardContent: ICardContent = {
            userName: userName,
            type: "comment",
            action: "commented",
            comment: comment,
            isRequestor: false,
          }

          // Prepare response message
          const encodedDeeplink: string = constructDeeplink(data.ticket, data.ticketingAppUrl, data.channelId, data.entityId);
          const message: string = constructMessage(data.ticket, data.cardContent, encodedDeeplink, lang);
          const isPremium: boolean = await getPremium(tenantId);
          // const card = invokeSuccessResponse(encodedDeeplink, message, data);       

          // Save audit trail
          const insertCommentEndpoint: string = process.env["InsertCommentEndpoint"];
          try {
            await cosmosService.insertItem(insertCommentEndpoint + encodeQueryParams({ instanceId: data.ticket.instanceId }), { comment: newComment });
          } catch (error) {
            context.log(error);
          }

          // Send request to SendCardNotification API
          try {
            // Notification recipient id array
            let recipientIds: string[] = [];
            if (data.ticket.requestorId)
              recipientIds.push(data.ticket.requestorId)
            if (data.ticket.assigneeId)
              recipientIds.push(data.ticket.assigneeId)

            // If ticket have custom fields get people from them
            if (data.ticket.customFields) {
              // Get instance so we can get customFieldSetting
              const instanceContainer: Container = ticketDatabase.container(process.env["InstanceContainer"]);
              const { resource: instance } = await instanceContainer.item(data.ticket.instanceId, tenantId).read<IInstance>();

              // Create array for user who will receive the notification
              let activePersonaCustomFields: ICustomField[] = [];
              if (instance.customFieldsLeft)
                activePersonaCustomFields.push(...instance.customFieldsLeft);
              if (instance.customFieldsRight)
                activePersonaCustomFields.push(...instance.customFieldsRight);
              activePersonaCustomFields = activePersonaCustomFields.filter((value) => value.type.key === "6_peoplepicker");
              activePersonaCustomFields = activePersonaCustomFields.filter((value) => value.isReceiveNotification);

              if (activePersonaCustomFields.length > 0) {
                for (const fields of activePersonaCustomFields) {
                  if (data.ticket.customFields[fields.id]?.length > 0) {
                    const personas: IPersonaProps[] = data.ticket.customFields[fields.id];

                    for (const element of personas) {
                      recipientIds.push(element.id)
                    }

                  }
                }
              }
            }

            // Remove message sender from recipient list
            recipientIds = recipientIds.filter((id) => id !== userId);

            // Get unique notification recipient array
            const uniqueRecipientIds: string[] = [... new Set(recipientIds)];

            context.log("Sending notifications");
            for (const id of uniqueRecipientIds) {
             await this.sendNotification(cardContent, id, tenantId, data);
            }

            card = NotificationCard(encodedDeeplink, message, data, true, isPremium, lang);
            const cardAttachment: Attachment = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card);
            const activityPayload = MessageFactory.attachment(cardAttachment);
            activityPayload.id = turnContext.activity.replyToId;

            context.log("Updating cards");
            await turnContext.updateActivity(activityPayload);
            
          } catch (error) {
            context.log(error)
          }
        }
      }
      const cardRes = {
        statusCode: StatusCodes.OK,
        type: 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive',
        value: card
      };
      const res = {
        status: StatusCodes.OK,
        body: cardRes
      };
      return res;
    }
  }
```

It actually does not matter what I do on the card, even if I do nothing and then only return the InvokeResponse, the error still happens.

### Expected behavior

The card is updated without any error message shown.

### Screenshots

[image: WhatsApp Image 2023-02-10 at 17 00 37]

Comment: Does that only happen on mobile?

Comment: Yes, this only happens on Teams mobile client.

Comment: hmm weird..that makes it harder to debug. I haven't done a lot of mobile stuff sadly, in the browser / desktop version you can get the developer tools and see some console errors, often that helped identify a problem. 

Does the request end up with your server and the answer throws the error or don't you get the request at all?

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't debug it from the app as well that's why I'm still.
The request does end up on my server and I can process it just fine, it's just that before the request is finished and the card is updated by my server, the error appears.

But, after doing some trial and error I found that the error happens on these conditions:
- The card is opened on Teams android client
- The card must contain an Input.Text and Submit.Action components on it.

In the end I refactored my code to use Action.Submit instead, and it works just fine.

Comment: The User Specific Card returned by the bot is sent only to the specific client that requested for it. For example, if a user switches to a different client, such as from desktop to mobile, then another invoke event is triggered to fetch the refreshed card. 
Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/universal-actions-for-adaptive-cards/user-specific-views?tabs=mobile%2CC#invoke-response-to-return-adaptive-cards

Comment: We have tested below NodeJS sample where the Adaptive card with Action.Execute has send.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-sequential-flow-adaptive-cards/nodejs
Its working fine at our end. We are not getting "Something Went Wrong" error.
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/92150070/219363991-e02d091f-c85b-45de-a226-eeb16ef39fd0.mp4
Could you please test this sample at your end. And check if you are getting same error for this sample also?